# jasper report:cannot be cast error

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a project in which the jasper report is created from the java method.  My jasper code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="balance" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="30" bottomMargin="30" isFloatColumnFooter="true" >
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <style name="Table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FF0000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="TableHeader" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#006F3A"/>
    <style name="TableFooter" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#C0C0C0"/>
    <subDataset name="TableData" >
        <field name="participantName" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="familySize" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="participantAge" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <title>
        <band height="150">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement style="Table" x="0" y="50" width="555" height="100" />
                <c:table xmlns:c="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="TableData" />
                    <c:column width="80" >
                        <c:columnHeader style="TableHeader" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <box leftPadding="10">
                                <pen lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="70" height="30" >
                                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{participantName}!= null)]]></printWhenExpression>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </c:columnHeader>
                        <c:detailCell height="15" rowSpan="1">
                            <box leftPadding="10">
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="70" height="15" />
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{participantName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </c:detailCell>
                    </c:column>
                    <c:column width="80" >
                        <c:columnHeader style="TableHeader" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <box leftPadding="10">
                                <pen lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="70" height="30" >
                                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{familySize}!= null)]]></printWhenExpression>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[FSize]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </c:columnHeader>
                        <c:detailCell height="15" rowSpan="1">
                            <box leftPadding="10">
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="70" height="15" />
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{familySize}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </c:detailCell>
                    </c:column>
                    <c:column width="80" >
                        <c:columnHeader style="TableHeader" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <box leftPadding="10">
                                <pen lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="70" height="30" >
                                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{participantAge}!= null)]]></printWhenExpression>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Age]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </c:columnHeader>
                        <c:detailCell height="15" rowSpan="1">
                            <box leftPadding="10">
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="70" height="15" />
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{participantAge}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </c:detailCell>
                    </c:column>
                </c:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

The problem is that during the runtime i got the below error:
Could not create the report stream org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 26; columnNumber: 30; Error at line 26 char 30: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignComponentElement cannot be cast to net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRBoxContainer.
Please help me to fix this and thanks in advance..

Comment: Hi, did you found a sollution?

Comment: yeah.. just upgrade the jar files dude..

Answer (score 0):

the above problem had cleared for me when i upgraded the jar- "jasperreports" from "3.1.2 to 3.7.2". Also i have upgraded itext.jar to 2.1.5  and poi.jar to 3.5 FINAL to fix the font issue and pdf export issue. I Hope it will works for all..